# hypothesis spaces knowing a neural network?

Tags: neural-network

So I'm studying for an artificial intelligence exam, and I see this question :

Knowing e) is your neural network, which is the corresponding hypothesis spaces?

I know that the answer is b), but I don't have any explanation as to why it is b). I'm a bit clueless as to what I have to do here...

[image: figure]

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question in your artificial intelligence exam consists in finding the values x and y so that the output is "true" or "false".

The figure (e) shows a small feedforward neural network. The output of a neuron is a function of the weighted sum of every inputs (and the bias, represented in your figure by vertical arrows). For example, the top-left neuron output is a function of `10*x + 10*y -10`. That means the output of this neuron is `output1 = f(10*x + 10*y - 10)`. This function `f` is called the *activation function*.
Here neurons may be considered as *perceptrons*. Perceptrons are the simplest models of neurons : their activation function is a step function : `f(u) = 1 if u > 0 and f(u) = 0 otherwise`.

The aim of the question is to find for which values of x and y the output of your network is 1/true/positive.

To do so, you basically just compute outputs of your network's neurons and find characteristic of the network. 
**Top-left neuron** : the output is 1 if `10*x + 10*y -10 > 0 <=>  x + y - 1 > 0`, 0 otherwise.
**Bottom-left neuron** : the output is 1 if `-10*x -10*y +30 > 0 <=> x + y < 3`, 0 otherwise.

The last neuron is a very basic neuron that works as a *logical AND*. If both values are true/1, then the output is 1 because `1+1-1.5 = 0.5 > 0`, the output is 0 otherwise. Therefore, the hypothesis space of this network is the *intersection* of the two previous spaces, ie. **the intersection of x + y - 1 > 0 and x + y < 3, which is (b).**